# Get past times new roman font installation

Tags: 15.10

Can someone tell me how to get past this image in the terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiHcM.png)

Comment: i cannot hit the <ok>

Comment: you are right*_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to highlight the `OK` button. Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can't use your mouse cursor in the terminal, so it's handy to know the general keyboard operations.